# Angular view is not loading but controller is

Tags: javascript, angularjs, url-routing, angularjs-routing, angularjs-controller

I have routes defined for a couple of views in Angular, one is the default 'Tickets' and the other is an edit view 'Ticket'. For some reason when I code the 'Edit' as a url the Ticket route opens fine. If I code the 'Edit' link using ng-click to run a method on the controller and change the location (ie. $location.path('/ticket/2')), it loads the correct controller 'TicketController' but never seems to load the view. In fact is loads the correct controller and then the default controller after that.

In the following Plunker you'll see two edit links for each detail item, 'Edit' is the url with an href set (works fine), the other 'Edit 2' is using the ng-click directive.

http://plnkr.co/edit/aY7fSvVJCIaVYnCHXcq6?p=preview

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('SimpleTicket', ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(function ($httpProvider, $routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.
            when('/ticket/:ticketId',
                {
                    templateUrl: 'ticket.html',
                    controller: 'TicketController as vm'
                }).
            when('/', {
                templateUrl: 'tickets.html',
                controller: 'TicketsController as vm'
            }).
            otherwise({
                redirectTo: '/'
            });

    });

    var TicketController = function ($scope, $log, $routeParams, $location) {
        var vm = this;
        $log.log('TicketController');
        var saveTicket = function () {
          $log.log('Item saved')
          $location.path('/');
        };

        vm.saveTicket = saveTicket;

        vm.ticket = {TicketId:2,Title:'Ticket 2',Body:'Body 2'};

    };
    app.controller("TicketController", TicketController);

    var TicketsController = function ($location, $log) {
        var vm = this;
        $log.log('TicketsController');

        var editTicket = function () {
            $log.log('editTicket');
            $location.path('/ticket/2');
        };
        vm.editTicket = editTicket;

        vm.tickets = [{TicketId:1,Title:'Ticket 1',Body:'Body 1'},
            {TicketId:2,Title:'Ticket 2',Body:'Body 2'}];

    };

    app.controller("TicketsController", TicketsController);



}());
```

Comment: My gosh this code is a messy. Try looking at https://github.com/angular/angular-seed to get a good idea how to organize your controllers, app.js, etc.

Comment: @MohamedElMahallawy - thanks for the link, this isn't my production code just a simple mock up for demonstration purposes

Comment: @MohamedElMahallawy - I've thought about your comment for a while now and it really doesn't bring anything to the table. You should try and focus on solving the question instead criticizing the code.

Comment: Sorry should have been more supportive and useful. Just trying to help by pointing out a resource!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the index.html you have to fix the extra double quote in `ng-app` as @brygiger said.

Also in tickets.html you have the extra # in href, it isn't needed as you can see here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngHref

```
<a ng-href="ticket/{{ticket.TicketId}}">edit</a> | 
<a href="" ng-click="vm.editTicket()">edit 2</a>
http://plnkr.co/edit/AuFnB7dV1YOkTuQiqxvg
```

See the plunker for the fixed version

Answer (score 2):

Just remove `href="#"` to `href=""` from `tickets.html`

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/Dzy8afdCjMz7ALBB4E9R?p=preview)